# How can a file.py containing grid() can be imported properly into a file.py containing pack()?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

this is the main file that will import another file
File1

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time
tk=Tk()
tk.title("App Manager")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=460,height=500,bg='black',bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_text(230,50,text="App Manager",font=('Bold',50),fill="gold")
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
class ball:
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(0,0,15,15,fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,100,100)
        start=[-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4]
        random.shuffle(start)
        self.x=start[0]
        self.y=-4
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1]<=0:
            self.y=4
        if pos[3]>=self.canvas_height:
           self.y=-4
        if pos[0]<=0:
            self.x=4
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=-4
class b:
    def pong():
        tk.destroy()
        import PONG
    def bounce():
        tk.destroy()
        import BOUNCE
    def calculator():
        import CALCULATOR
    def quit1():
        tk.destroy()
b1=Button(tk,text="Play PONG",font=('Bold',15),bg='brown',fg='gold',command=b.pong)
b1.pack(side=LEFT)
b2=Button(tk,text="Play BOUNCE",font=('Bold',15),bg='brown',fg='gold',command=b.bounce)
b2.pack(side=LEFT)
b3=Button(tk,text="CALCULATOR",font=('Bold',15),bg='brown',fg='gold',command=b.calculator)
b3.pack(side=LEFT)
b4=Button(tk,text="Quit",font=('Bold',15),bg='brown',fg='gold',command=b.quit1)
b4.pack(side=RIGHT)
ball=ball(canvas,"white")
while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

The second file is a code of calculator.
This file of calculator works properly when run independently.
But when it is run by clicking 'CALCULATOR' button through file 1 then buttons of file 2 does not work. May be that is because file1 contains pack() and file2 contains grid().
this is the file to be imported
File2

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time
tk=Tk()
tk.resizable(width=False,height=False)
tk.title("CALCULATOR")
tk.configure(bg='black')
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
frame=Frame(tk)
frame.pack()
frame.grid(row=1,column=0)
frame.configure(bg="black")
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=600,height=150,bg="black",bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas.create_text(300,75,text="CALCULATOR",font=('Bold',50),fill="gold")
equa=""
equation=StringVar()
calculation=Label(frame,textvariable=equation,font=  ("Bold",40),background='black',fg='gold')
equation.set("Enter your equation:")
calculation.grid(columnspan=4)
tk.update()
class ball:
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(0,0,15,15,fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,100,100)
        start=[-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4]
        random.shuffle(start)
        self.x=start[0]
        self.y=-4
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1]<=0:
            self.y=2
        if pos[3]>=self.canvas_height:
            self.y=-2
        if pos[0]<=0:
            self.x=2
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=-2
def press(num):
    global equa
    equa=equa+str(num)
    equation.set(equa)
def equal():
    global equa
    total=str(eval(equa))
    equation.set(total)
    equa=""
def clear():
    global equa
    equa=""
    equation.set("")
equal=Button(frame,text="=",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=equal)
equal.grid(row=4,column=2)
clear=Button(frame,text="C",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=clear)
clear.grid(row=0,column=4)
button0=Button(frame,text="0",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(0))
button0.grid(row=4,column=1)
button1=Button(frame,text="1",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(1))
button1.grid(row=1,column=0)
button2=Button(frame,text="2",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(2))
button2.grid(row=1,column=1)
button3=Button(frame,text="3",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(3))
button3.grid(row=1,column=2)
button4=Button(frame,text="4",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(4))
button4.grid(row=2,column=0)
button5=Button(frame,text="5",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(5))
button5.grid(row=2,column=1)
button6=Button(frame,text="6",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(6))
button6.grid(row=2,column=2)
button7=Button(frame,text="7",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(7))
button7.grid(row=3,column=0)
button8=Button(frame,text="8",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(8))
button8.grid(row=3,column=1)
button9=Button(frame,text="9",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(9))
button9.grid(row=3,column=2)
plus=Button(frame,text="+",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('+'))
plus.grid(row=1,column=3)
minus=Button(frame,text="-",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('-'))
minus.grid(row=2,column=3)
multiply=Button(frame,text="x",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('*'))
multiply.grid(row=3,column=3)
divide=Button(frame,text="/",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('/'))
divide.grid(row=4,column=3)
dot=Button(frame,text=".",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('.'))
dot.grid(row=4,column=0)
remainder=Button(frame,text="%",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('%'))
remainder.grid(row=1,column=4)
power=Button(frame,text="^",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('**'))
power.grid(row=2,column=4)
leftbracket=Button(frame,text="(",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press('('))
leftbracket.grid(row=3,column=4)
rightbracket=Button(frame,text=")",font=("Bold",40),fg="gold",bg="black",bd=0,command=lambda:press(')'))
rightbracket.grid(row=4,column=4)
ball=ball(canvas,"white")
while 1:
    ball.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rewrite one or both of your files. They each contain a root window, but a tkinter program can have only a single root window.

If you intend for something to be importable, you should design it to be importable. Usually that means that it doesn't have any executable code at the global scope. Instead, it should define functions and classes which can be used by the code doing the importing.

Comment: besides "CALCULATOR" file i have imported "PONG" and "BOUNCE" files which contain same tk=Tk() . They both get imported perfectly into "App Manager" file .

Comment: @KARPAT: ok. What am I supposed to do with that information?

Comment: All 4 files contains buttons but only the buttons of "CALCULATOR" file does not work. Maybe because buttons of "CALCULATOR" file contains "grid()" function.

Comment: Is there any function that can be used in place of "grid()" function that can work with "pack()" function? Because "grid()" does not work properly with "pack()".  All other three files contains "pack()".  Or the problem can be solved if somehow calculator buttons can be placed at proper positions using "pack()" . Thanks

Comment: @KARPAT: _" Is there any function that can be used in place of "grid()" function that can work with "pack()" function? "_ - yes, you can use `pack`. That's not the real problem. The real problem is that you're trying to combine everything with one geometry manager. Put the buttons in a frame, and you can use grid inside the frame. The frame itself you can put in the GUI using pack or anything else.